# Trying to implement CSS Animation

Tags: css

Hi I am trying to implement css animation, i have implemented @keyframes
but my animation is not applied to my div.

my keyframe is

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {
       opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
       opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

Please tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have done everything right but you haven't created the class which will implement animation

Create two css class as follows

```
.fadeIn {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

.animated {
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

animation-name is the name of your keyframes in your example i.e. fadeIn.

Now use those two class in your div where ever you want to implement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<style> 
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes mymove {
    0%   {top: 0px;opacity:0;}

    100% {top: 100px;opacity:1;}
}
</style>

<div></div>
```